# Is it possible to make xcode compiling no stop?

Tags: ios, iphone

When xcode compile a project, it always stop when encountrt some error.

Is it possible to make xcode compiling no stop?

I hope to count error amount.

your comment welcome

Comment: what is the xcode version ?

Comment: xcode version is 6.3.1

Comment: And what exactly would you like the compiler to do with said error? Resolve it himself? If it were possible, why would we need programmers?

Comment: @Lord Zsolt  I hope to estimate amount of error

Comment: this question makes sense. Xcode oftentimes stops compiling with one erroneous file, you fix the errors and have to start compiling again. When Xcode does not stop, you get a list of ALL (or at least significantly more) errors at one time

Comment: @IceFire You get more error *messages*; not the same thing as more *errors*.

Comment: @ScottHunter so? I did not say anything contradictory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to two possible solutions -

1. enable Xcode -> Preferences > General > Continue Building After Errors

[image]

2. Set a flag "-ferror-limit=0" to compiler flags in the project settings under the "Language" section of the "Build Settings" tab.

Comment: thanks! Also works with Xcode11

Answer (score 2):

Every `.m` (source) file is compiled separately, so you can always count how many files failed to compile.

Usually, you cannot count the errors in one single file. The reason is simple, the compiler cannot recover from some errors.

If you know something about compilers, there are two important phases - the syntax analysis and semantic analysis. Semantic analysis triggers errors such as "unknown variable" or "unknown method" and the compiler can usually recover pretty easily. The syntax analysis is a problem though. A missing brace, a missing semicolon, a missing parenthesis - all of those are errors triggered by syntax analysis. When an error is encountered, the compiler tries to recover so that it can continue the compilation. For instance, recovering from a missing parenthesis means adding the missing parenthesis and continue. Sometimes that works, other times it doesn't. If it doesn't, you will get tens or hundreds of errors. Then the compiler will stop. If there are too many errors, it doesn't make sense to try to compile.